# How to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-3} \frac{k}{k+1} \frac{3^k}{k!} $.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

I've been dealing probability questions lately, and I had to calculate this sum : $\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-3} \frac{k}{k+1} \frac{3^k}{k!} $ , which I have no idea how to bring to to an easier form, or for example extract from it something that is  known. Its good to mention that its a result of multiplying with Poisson function of probability with parameter $3$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{k!}\frac{k}{k+1} = \frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if we let $k=n-1$,

$$\frac k{k+1}\frac{3^k}{k!}=\frac{k3^k}{(k+1)!}=\frac13\frac{(n-1)3^n}{n!}=\frac13\left(\frac{3^n}{(n-1)!}-\frac{3^n}{n!}\right)$$

Summing from $n=1$ to infinity yields

$$3e^3S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{3^n}{(n-1)!}-\frac{3^n}{n!}\right)=3e^3-e^3+1=1+2e^3$$

Thus,

> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-3}\frac k{k+1}\frac{3^k}{k!}=\frac{1+2e^3}{3e^3}$$

Comment: I'm so sorry. i had edited the question.

Comment: Beautifully answered!

Comment: You really treat this as Art!

Comment: :-) Thanks guys.